# Finding a node in xml file with libxml2

Tags: c, xml-parsing, libxml2

I am trying to write a function that will find a node with a specified name in a xml file.
The problem is that the function never finds the specified node.

```
xmlNodePtr findNodeByName(xmlNodePtr rootnode, const xmlChar * nodename)
{
    xmlNodePtr node = rootnode;
    if(node == NULL){
        log_err("Document is empty!");
        return NULL;
    }

    while(node != NULL){

        if(!xmlStrcmp(node->name, nodename)){
            return node; 
        }
        else if(node->children != NULL){
            node = node->children; 
            xmlNodePtr intNode =  findNodeByName(node, nodename); 
            if(intNode != NULL){
                return intNode;
            }
        }
        node = node->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

I can see in the debugger that function does go deep into the sub nodes but still returns NULL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the XPath API?

Comment: No, there is no reason:) I just started using libxml2 so I'm only playing around with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is correct. Add a debugging line to see why it doesn't work in your case. For example:

```
    printf("xmlStrcmp(%s, %s)==%d\n", node->name, nodename,
        xmlStrcmp(node->name, nodename));
```

But you don't really need that function. You may use [xmlXPathEval](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xpath.html#xmlXPathEval).

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna try the XPath API then...as soon as I get my function working;). Thanks

Comment: Function is not correct. I've given specified the correction in the next answer. Please check.

Answer (score 8):

```
else if(node->children != NULL) {
    node = node->children; 
    xmlNodePtr intNode =  findNodeByName(node, nodename); 
    if (intNode != NULL) {
        return intNode;
    }
}
```

This should be:

```
else if (node->children != NULL) {
    xmlNodePtr intNode =  findNodeByName(node->children, nodename); 
    if(intNode != NULL) {
        return intNode;
    }
}
```

and it works fine

Answer (score -1):

When @jarekczek mentionned XPath, he means to use XPath instead of your function.

With XPath, your function will become:

```
xmlNodeSetPtr findNodesByName(xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr rootnode, const xmlChar* nodename) {
    // Create xpath evaluation context
    xmlXPathContextPtr xpathCtx = xmlXPathNewContext(doc);
    if(xpathCtx == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: unable to create new XPath context\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // The prefix './/' means the nodes will be selected from the current node
    const xmlChar* xpathExpr = xmlStrncatNew(".//", nodename, -1);
    xmlXPathObjectPtr xpathObj = xmlXPathNodeEval(rootnode, xpathExpr, xpathCtx);
    if(xpathObj == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: unable to evaluate xpath expression \"%s\"\n", xpathExpr);
        xmlXPathFreeContext(xpathCtx);
        return NULL;
    }

    xmlXPathFreeContext(xpathCtx);

    return xpathObj->nodesetval;
}
```

Note: This function returns all the nodes matching 'nodename'. If you only want the first node, you could replace `return xpathObj->nodesetval;` by:

```
if (xpathObj->nodesetval->nodeNr > 0) {
    return xpathObj->nodesetval->nodeTab[0];
} else {
    return NULL;
}
```

You could also append `[1]` to the XPath query to optimize your query.

Comment: shouldn't the code snippet also have xmlFree(xpathExpr) to avoid a memory leak from xmlStrncatNew?

Comment: Also `xpathObj` should be freed using `xmlXPathFreeObject(xpathObj)`